# Ubuntu zooms into my wallpaper on one monitor, but leaves other normal

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors, desktop-background

I have a 23" 1080p widescreen in the center and a 19" 1280x1024 screen on the left.

Whenever I change the wallpaper, it looks nice on both of them, but a second later the 23" one zooms in and starts to look awful.

- the wallpaper is 1080p
- Picture:

http://www.upload.ee/image/3512209/messed_up_desktop.png

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a switch under the selected wallpaper in Appearance settings was marked zoom, set it to fill and fixed it.